# IntelliSense: no operator "+" matches these operands

Tags: c++, operators, operands

Hi there, I am new to C++ and I got this error.
IntelliSense: no operator "+" matches these operands
The problematic line of code is:

```
cout << i << "\t" << temp->VehicleNo + "\n";
```

Link to picture showing context of error

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aTbwj.jpg

Comment: Can you show your code and the error trace? That would help.

Comment: Can you show us that "Picture of Error"?

Comment: It's difficult to say specifically, because you haven't posted any code.  But in general, this means that you're trying to add two things that can't be added.

Comment: please use something else to upload the picture, or link the picture directly. Or even better, paste the relevant (!) code directly into the question.

Comment: Picture of error
http://i.imgur.com/IgKHn.jpg

Comment: Can't you just replace `+` with `<<` ?

Comment: You should paste the problematic code (`cout << i << "\t" << temp->VehicleNo + "\n"`) into the question, along with the text of the error. We'll also need to know the type of `VehicleNo` to figure out why you can't add a string literal to it. But as @gogowitczak says, you almost certainly want `<<` rather than `+`.

Comment: Hi there, I tried and I got this http://i.imgur.com/GIZ6J.png

Comment: @LawrenceWong: What is the type of `temp->VehicleNo`? And please post text, not images.

Comment: Please could you show us the definition for the "Node" class/struct?

Comment: Use `<< endl` instead of `+ "\n"`.

Comment: Did you remember to `#include <string>` in this code?

Comment: We need to know the type of `VehicleNo`, and the code declaring that type, else answering this will be as good as impossible.

Answer (score 1):

So, `temp->VehicleNo` is object of class `Vehicle` and this class has a member `VehicleNo` of type `std::string`. To display that string you need this code:

```
cout << i << "\t" << temp->VehicleNo.VehicleNo << "\n";
```

I would propose that you rename `Node::VehicleNo` to `Node::Vehicle`, so that in the code above the code would be `temp->Vehicle.VehicleNo`, which makes more sense.

Comment: Hi there, VehicleNo is a string.
So how do i resolve this problem?

Comment: Hi there,
Error 1 error C2039: 'c_str' : is not a member of 'Vehicle'

 2 IntelliSense: class "Vehicle" has no member "c_str"

How do i resolve this?

Comment: Then VehicleNo is not `std::string`, but of type `Vehicle`, which is a class. We need to know what are the interesting members of this class.

Comment: And please do not put an image of the class. Copy and paste relevant code into your original question.

Comment: Under the vehicle class,
I have string VehicleNo; declared inside the class.

Comment: Try `temp->VehicleNo.VehicleNo` or `temp->VehicleNo.VehicleNo.c_str()`, or even `temp->VehicleNo->VehicleNo.c_str()`. It would be faster if you would provide enough information, so that we don't have to play the guessing game.

Comment: You don't need `c_str()` to print a `std::string` to `std::cout`.